# How to solder high amperage PCB wire lugs

Tags: pcb-assembly, high-current, wire-terminals

My concerns are how to successfully hand solder a double-sided, 4oz copper PCB.

The plated-through holes in the board have no thermal reliefs and are attached to the power and ground planes. The board material is FR4 with a thickness of 0.06".

The components are comprised of pc auto fuse clips and 2/0 awg 175 A lugs. The legs on the fuse clips are .016" thick brass, whereas the power lugs have 2 legs that are .344" X .078" thick copper.

Can anyone offer up any insight as to manufacturing process and tools to best accomplish this assembly?

Comment: Heat. Lots of it.

Comment: Preheat the board if possible.  And yes, lots of heat.  I just looked up the soldering guidelines for a power supply module and the manufacturer recommends temperatures up to 430C.  Don't forget flux too.

Comment: The answer is different if it's hand solder vs going through a wave or something like that.

Comment: To get a really sleek joint, even a (big) soldering iron may not be sufficient, depending on the size of the part. In that case, mount a hot air fan to assist, put the board over a hotplate or toaster, so the soldering iron only has to provide the last 50 Kelvin or so.